# Karma/Mocha tests intermittently cause full page reload in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I have an Angular project unit tested with Karma and Mocha. Intermittently (about one out of every 9~10 runs) the tests fail in Chrome with the message:

> Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.2) ERROR
>
> Some of your tests did a full page reload!

It only seems to happen on Chrome (also testing on Firefox and PhantomJS). The project is using the mocha, chai, and sinon frameworks, and the ng-html2js preprocessor for compiling templates into an angular module.

I am loading all JS and partials in my Karma configuration:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'app.js',
  'controllers/*.js',
  'services/*.js',
  'directives/*.js',
  'partials/*.html'
],
```

The error doesn't seem to be attributed to any specific test, as I have run it with only a service returning a resource and that is still throwing the error intermittently. I have seen other similar questions asked that deal specifically with the ui-router framework but I am not using that (simply using ngRoute for routing), and I've also loaded tests without the route code (took it out of karma.conf.js) and still run into problems.

I've run a single test that doesn't use $location, $window, or any other service that would attempt to reload the page and still run into the issue.

Is there any configuration in the framework that could be causing these problems? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Things like this can be tricky to find, but you can track down causes of this issue with the following steps.

1) Run your app with the following code included before anything else and DevTools (Chrome, in this case) open.

```
console.profile('cause of reload');

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
  console.profileEnd('cause of reload');
  debugger;
});
```

> If the reload you're looking for is about to happen, you should be taken to the "Sources" view of Chrome DevTools with the app paused at the `debugger` line.

2) Navigate to the "Profiles" tab.

3) Select the profile we created, from the left nav.

4) Choose the "Charts" view from the dropdown menu at the top.

5) Enter Command+F (or Ctrl+F on Windows) and search for "location".

6) Use the up and down arrows in the search box to jump to the last occurring matches for that phrase.

5) Hit enter in the search field to jump to the match.

5) Look back through the call stack for code you recognise.

Comment: When you say  "with the following code included before anything else", where exactly do you mean?

Comment: before any other lines of JavaScript code, so that snippet is the first to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug of Karma as far as I understand: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1101